Low dimensional homotopy groups of $\operatorname{Top}(4)$
$\DeclareMathOperator\Top{Top}$I would like to compute $\pi_3\Top(4)$ and $\pi_4\Top(4)$. It is known that $\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow \Top/O$ is 5-connected and
$$
  \pi_k(\Top/O) =
  \begin{cases}
    0,  & k = 0,1,2,4; \\
    \mathbb{Z}/2, & k = 3 .
  \end{cases}
$$
The long exact sequence of homotopy groups for fibre sequence $\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow BO(4) \rightarrow B\Top(4)$ is:
$$\pi_5\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow \pi_4 O(4) \rightarrow \pi_4 \Top(4)\rightarrow \pi_4\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow \pi_3 O(4) \rightarrow \pi_3 \Top(4) \rightarrow\pi_3\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow \pi_2 O(4)$$
By plugging in the known groups ($SO(4) \cong S^3 \times \mathbb{R}P^3$) we get two exact sequences: $$\pi_5\Top(4)/O(4) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow \pi_4 \Top(4) \rightarrow 0$$ $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \pi_3 \Top(4) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow 0$$
I can also show that $\pi_4\Top(4)$ is at least $\mathbb{Z}/2$ by comparing to the same long exact sequence for $O(5), \Top(5)$, but it still may be $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$. Is there a way to finish the computation?

You might like to look at Randall (On 4-dimensional bundle theories. Differential topology, foliations, and group actions (Rio de Janeiro, 1992), 217–233. Contemp. Math., 161, 1994) says that $\pi_3(STOP(4))$ is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. In other words, it seems that your exact sequence at the bottom splits. There's some more information in his related publication with Schweitzer (On Foliations, Concordance Spaces, and the Smale Conjectures) in the same volume.

It is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, see this note.

Did you write this specifically to answer the OP's question??

No, it's an unpublished note that has been sitting on my laptop for years.

Thank you for sharing the note! It answers my question together with the reference from Danny Ruberman's comment.
